# Where can I retrace changes made to dart:ui package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, path, dart-ui

I would love to see the git history for dart:ui, but I'm not sure if it is public?
I checked the github of dart_lang, but I didn't find anything.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html

Why am I looking for this?
There have been some changes in painting.dart I'd love to understand better, because we have issues with this after Flutter release 3.13.0

I now found this: https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/flutter-3.13-candidate.19/lib/ui/painting/path.cc
This has a lot of the same functions I see in my flutter project, but a lot is also missing.
We extended "Path" which was now changed to _NativePath and is not extendable anymore...

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/flutter/engine/tree/main/lib/ui